# Ytplayer in bootstrap responsive layout

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap, responsive-design

I have a gallery that loads videos into a ytplayer from http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/swfobject/2/swfobject.js, my question is, how do I make it responsive?

Right now, I have multiple players for each screen size, but the thing is, I need them to load videos linked from the gallery, and it simply doesn't work other than with the first player. I've also tried naming them and then using different loadvideos for each one,

```
  <div class="span3"> <a href="#ytplayer" onClick="ytplayer_loadvideo( 'YOUTUBEID' );ytplayer2_loadvideo( 'YOUTUBEID' );ytplayer3_loadvideo( 'YOUTUBEID' );"><img src="http://i2.ytimg.com/vi/YOUTUBEID/mqdefault.jpg" alt="name" />
```

but it doesn't seem to move past the error of not finding the first player (TypeError: Object # has no method 'loadVideoById').

they work fine with manual commands directed at just one player `ytplayer3_loadvideo('YOUTUBEID');`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I figured out a way.

If anyone is curious, I simply made separate video lists with single commands for each player. So for example, on resolution A, it's showing ytplayerA and listA, on resolution B, ytplayerB and listB and so on.

Yes, it's bulky and heavy, but it works as needed.